# Open the same serial port multiple times

Tags: c#, winforms, serial-port

An unhandled exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in System.dll
Additional information: Access to the port 'COM3' is denied.
The error happens when i open the port for the second time (when i open the this form again)

```
using DI_120_Interface.Class;
using MetroFramework.Forms;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace DI_120_Interface
{
    public partial class frmAddInventoryTransItem3 : MetroForm
    {
        public frmAddInventoryTrans ReceivingAdd { set; get; }
        public frmEditInventoryTrans ReceivingEdit { set; get; }

        string inv_type2 = null, action2 = null, document2 = null;
        static SerialPort _serialPort;
        static INIFile settings = new INIFile("C:\\Lateco\\settings.ini");
        private string weight;

        public frmAddInventoryTransItem3(object parent, string action, string inv_type, string document)
        {
            if (inv_type == "Receiving in LAVI" && action == "add")
                this.ReceivingAdd = (frmAddInventoryTrans)parent;
            else if (inv_type == "Receiving in LAVI" && action == "edit")
                this.ReceivingEdit = (frmEditInventoryTrans)parent;

            InitializeComponent();
            inv_type2 = inv_type;
            action2 = action;
            document2 = document;
        }

        private void frmAddInventoryTransItem3_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtQty.Text = 1.ToString();
            txtWeight.Text = 0.ToString("N3");
            this.ActiveControl = txtPLU;

            string portname, baudrate, parity, databits, stopbits, handshake;

            portname = settings.Read("SERIAL PORT PROPERTIES", "PORT_NAME");
            baudrate = settings.Read("SERIAL PORT PROPERTIES", "BAUD_RATE");
            parity = settings.Read("SERIAL PORT PROPERTIES", "PARITY");
            databits = settings.Read("SERIAL PORT PROPERTIES", "DATA_BITS");
            stopbits = settings.Read("SERIAL PORT PROPERTIES", "STOP_BITS");
            handshake = settings.Read("SERIAL PORT PROPERTIES", "HANDSHAKE");

            _serialPort = new SerialPort(); //error here
            _serialPort.PortName = portname;
            _serialPort.BaudRate = int.Parse(baudrate);
            _serialPort.Parity = (Parity)Enum.Parse(typeof(Parity), parity, true);
            _serialPort.DataBits = int.Parse(databits);
            _serialPort.StopBits = (StopBits)Enum.Parse(typeof(StopBits), stopbits, true);
            _serialPort.Handshake = (Handshake)Enum.Parse(typeof(Handshake), handshake, true);

            _serialPort.Open();
            _serialPort.ReadTimeout = 200;
            if (_serialPort.IsOpen)
            {
                weight = "";
                txtWeight.Text = "000.000";
            }

            _serialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(serialPort1_DataReceived);
        }

        private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                weight = _serialPort.ReadExisting();
                weight = weight.Substring(0, 7);

                try
                {
                    if (this.InvokeRequired)
                        this.BeginInvoke(new EventHandler(DisplayText));
                }
                catch (ObjectDisposedException) { }
            }
            catch (TimeoutException) { }
        }

        private void txtPLU_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Enter)
            {
                e.Handled = true;
                this.ActiveControl = txtQty;
            }
        }

        private void txtQty_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Enter)
            {
                e.Handled = true;
                this.ActiveControl = txtWeight;
            }
        }

        private void txtWeight_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Enter)
            {
                e.Handled = true;
                this.ActiveControl = btnAddItem;
            }
        }

        private void btnAddItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string plu_code = txtPLU.Text;
            txtWarning.Text = "";

            if (IsNumeric(txtQty.Text) && IsNumeric(txtWeight.Text))
            {
                if (Convert.ToDecimal(txtQty.Text) == 0 || Convert.ToDecimal(txtWeight.Text) == 0)
                {
                    txtWarning.Text = "***Qty/Weight must not be equal to zero.***";
                    txtQty.Text = 1.ToString();
                    txtWeight.Text = 0.ToString("N3");
                    this.ActiveControl = txtQty;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (Functions.AddInventoryItemTempFromItemMasterUsingPLU(inv_type2, document2, plu_code, Convert.ToDecimal(txtQty.Text), Convert.ToDecimal(txtWeight.Text)))
                    {
                        txtPLU.Text = "";
                        txtQty.Text = 1.ToString();
                        txtWeight.Text = 0.ToString("N3");
                        this.ActiveControl = txtPLU;

                        if (inv_type2 == "Receiving in LAVI" && action2 == "add")
                            this.ReceivingAdd.UpdateQtyWeightAmount();
                        else if (inv_type2 == "Receiving in LAVI" && action2 == "edit")
                            this.ReceivingEdit.UpdateQtyWeightAmount();

                        //this.Close();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        txtWarning.Text = "***PLU not found.***";
                        txtPLU.Text = "";
                        txtQty.Text = 1.ToString();
                        txtWeight.Text = 0.ToString("N3");
                        this.ActiveControl = txtPLU;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                txtWarning.Text = "***Please enter numeric value/s only.***";
                txtQty.Text = 1.ToString();
                txtWeight.Text = 0.ToString("N3");
                this.ActiveControl = txtQty;
            }
        }

        private bool IsNumeric(string s)
        {
            float output;
            return float.TryParse(s, out output);
        }

        private void DisplayText(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtWeight.Text = weight;
        }

        class INIFile
        {
            private string filePath;

            [DllImport("kernel32")]
            private static extern long WritePrivateProfileString(string section, string key, string val, string filePath);

            [DllImport("kernel32")]
            private static extern int GetPrivateProfileString(string section, string key, string def, StringBuilder retVal, int size, string filePath);

            public INIFile(string filePath)
            {
                this.filePath = filePath;
            }

            public void Write(string section, string key, string value)
            {
                WritePrivateProfileString(section, key, value, this.filePath);
            }

            public string Read(string section, string key)
            {
                StringBuilder SB = new StringBuilder(255);
                int i = GetPrivateProfileString(section, key, "", SB, 255, this.filePath);
                return SB.ToString();
            }

            public string FilePath
            {
                get { return this.filePath; }
                set { this.filePath = value; }
            }
        }

        private void frmMain_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (_serialPort.IsOpen)
                _serialPort.Close();
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: You simply can't open it twice.

Comment: Please try to narrow down the error you're receiving, don't just supply the entire program. For example, what line does the error happen? Try to provide *as little code as possible* which still exhibits the behaviour. Usually, just doing this is enough to let you figure out where the bug is by yourself.

Comment: When asking a question it is good practice to provide a **minimal** , working code sample. Just for the future.

Comment: The error is occurring when you open the form twice so don't open the form twice.  See my two form project to learn how to open form only once : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975508/reach-control-from-another-page-asp-net

Comment: @jdweng You don't even know if it is necessary in OPs solution to open the form twice. Your suggestion is no fix to the problem.

Comment: The serial port is being opened in the Load() method.  So the load is being called twice.  My solution will not call the Load() twice.

Comment: @jdweng And what if the form needs to be opened multiple times?

Comment: Look at my code.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution to this problem could be to have the serial connection in a separate class and provide an event if you received data. Each window can then add an event handler for this event. In the following code, I tried to maintain only the parts necessary to the serial connection. I couldn't really try it on my machine, so there might be some minor problems. Also the event is very basic. It would be better to define a delegate that meets your specific needs:

```
public class SerialConnection
{
    INIFile settings = new INIFile("C:\\Lateco\\settings.ini");
    public SerialPort SerialPort { get; set; }
    static SerialConnection connection= null;
    public event EventHandler WeightReceived;

    public static SerialConnection OpenConnection()
    {
        if(connection == null)
        {
            connection = new SerialConnection();
            string portname, baudrate, parity, databits, stopbits, handshake;

            portname = settings.Read("SERIAL PORT PROPERTIES", "PORT_NAME");
            baudrate = settings.Read("SERIAL PORT PROPERTIES", "BAUD_RATE");
            parity = settings.Read("SERIAL PORT PROPERTIES", "PARITY");
            databits = settings.Read("SERIAL PORT PROPERTIES", "DATA_BITS");
            stopbits = settings.Read("SERIAL PORT PROPERTIES", "STOP_BITS");
            handshake = settings.Read("SERIAL PORT PROPERTIES", "HANDSHAKE");

            connection.SerialPort = new SerialPort(); //error here
            connection.SerialPort.PortName = portname;
            connection.SerialPort.BaudRate = int.Parse(baudrate);
            connection.SerialPort.Parity = (Parity)Enum.Parse(typeof(Parity), parity, true);
            connection.SerialPort.DataBits = int.Parse(databits);
            connection.SerialPort.StopBits = (StopBits)Enum.Parse(typeof(StopBits), stopbits, true);
            connection.SerialPort.Handshake = (Handshake)Enum.Parse(typeof(Handshake), handshake, true);

            connection.SerialPort.Open();
            connection.SerialPort.ReadTimeout = 200;
            connection.SerialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(connection.serialPort1_DataReceived);
        }

        private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                weight = SerialPort.ReadExisting();
                weight = weight.Substring(0, 7);

                WeightReceived?.Invoke(weight, new EventArgs());
            }
            catch (TimeoutException) { }
        }

        return connection;
    }

    public void CloseConnection()
    {
        if (SerialPort.IsOpen)
                SerialPort.Close();
    }

    ~SerialConnection()
    {
        if (SerialPort.IsOpen)
                SerialPort.Close();
    }
}
```

In the `Form` use it like this:

```
public partial class frmAddInventoryTransItem3 : MetroForm
    {
        public frmAddInventoryTrans ReceivingAdd { set; get; }
        public frmEditInventoryTrans ReceivingEdit { set; get; }

        string inv_type2 = null, action2 = null, document2 = null;
        private string weight;
        private SerialConnection sc = null;

        private void frmAddInventoryTransItem3_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtQty.Text = 1.ToString();
            txtWeight.Text = 0.ToString("N3");
            this.ActiveControl = txtPLU;

            sc = SerialConnection.OpenConnection();
            sc.WeightReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(WeightReceived);
        }

        private void WeightReceived(object weight, EventArgs e)
        {
                weight = weight as string;

                try
                {
                    if (this.InvokeRequired)
                        this.BeginInvoke(new EventHandler(DisplayText));
                }
                catch (ObjectDisposedException) { }
        }

        private void DisplayText(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtWeight.Text = weight;
        }
    }
}
```